Magical Sphere, rollerblades, and ants
Looking for a movie I watched growing up. Don't remember too much detail. 
What I remember:

Slightly futuristic
A group of kids roller blading
A sphere that was somewhat magical
One of the (bad) kids gets engulfed in ants due to sphere

I thought that the move was called "The Sphere". But it's not as far as I can find.

We don't unfortunately know when you were growing up .... can you tell us roughly when you saw the movie?

You got it. Man this brings back memories! Thanks a ton!!

Perhaps this is Solarbabies, an Action/Sci-Fi movie from 1986.
According to this Wikipedia plot summary:

The story is set in a post-apocalyptic future in which most of Earth's
  water has been controlled. The future is bleak and is controlled by
  the Eco Protectorate (a para-military organization that governs the
  planet's new order). There are also children, mostly teenagers, living
  in orphanages created by the Protectorate, designed to indoctrinate
  new recruits into their service. [...] The orphans play a rough sport which is a hybrid
  of lacrosse and roller-hockey. Playing is the only thing that unites
  them other than the futile attempts of the Protectorate to control
  them. 
While hiding in a cave, Daniel finds a mysterious orb with
  special powers. The orb is an alien intelligence called Bohdai, who
  miraculously restores Daniel's hearing and has other powers, such as
  creating rain indoors. 

